# Sorting Backbone collection alphabetically

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Is there a way to do this out of the box with the _.sortBy method or any other part of the library?

Comment: Your question says Underscore, but you accepted an answer from Backbone. I arrived at this page because I am actually looking for an Underscore answer, so this title is misleading. Please consider amending the title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you tagged your question with the backbone.js tag, I'm assuming you mean to sort a collection, you just need to provide a [comparator](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) function on your collection and backbone will keep the collection sorted.

If your question is specifically alphabeticical sorting, I  believe that is the default sort, from the backbone.js documentation (I linked to it above)

```
chapters.comparator = function(chapter) {
  return chapter.get("page");
};
```

Comment: This is actually exactly what I needed. I hadn't run into comparators in the docs until you pointed them out. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 25):

You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/uHtUX/)?

```
var array = [
    { name: "banana" },
    { name: "carrot" },
    { name: "apple" }
];

var sorted = _(array).sortBy("name");
```

I'd say it works out of the box.

If you wanted to sort an ordinary array of *strings*, you probably just want to use [`sort`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp):

```
var flatArray = ["banana", "carrot", "apple"];

flatArray.sort();
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uHtUX/1/). Also works.

Note that Underscore's `sortBy` returns a *new* array which is sorted, where JavaScript's built-in `sort` function sorts an array in place.

Comment: _.sortBy() will not work correctly if you write "Carrot" with capital C. "Carrot" will be at the first index. http://jsfiddle.net/uHtUX/39/

Comment: @Andrej "will not work correctly"? I think it's pretty reasonable that the default comparison function used for `sortBy` would follow standard alphanumeric ordering (i.e. just try `'a' < 'A'` vs. `'A' < 'a'` in your web console). If you wanted a case-insensitive sort you could supply a function to call `toLowerCase` on the values first, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uHtUX/40/

Comment: It's question of the definition. "alphabetically" normally means case-insensitive, like order of terms in a dictionary. Anything else is not really alphabetical...